# Difference between importing Handlebar templates and fetching them?

Tags: javascript, import, fetch, handlebars.js

I've seen people use fetch requests to get .hbs files that are already inside the server and could simply be imported using the import syntax. Why would that be? Is there a point to fetching files from inside the server? Wouldn't it be better to simply `export const studentTemplate = "*the template*"`? And wouldn't that allow for the simple export of the compiled function instead of the template itself? Are imports somehow slower (as far as I know, they shouldn't be as fetch requests deal with the network)?

E.g. instead of doing all theses activities - fetching the file from inside the server, registering all the partials necessary and then compiling the function to use - inside the file which has to output the HTML, wouldn't it be better to have a separate file which - imports the handlebars template instead of fetching it, registers the partials needed, compiles the function and only exports the function - and then just import the compiled function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to do this is to decrease initial page load time (by decreasing the size of a HTML/JS request). The templates can then either be:

- loaded on-demand when a user does an action that requires rendering that template, but this may result in some latency (requiring a spinner)
- or preloaded one by one in order of likelihood that the templates will be rendered, but this may result in unnecessary data fetching (a static import would too).

The *best* solution would be to precompile the templates as part of the build process, and include them in a JS bundle as dynamic imports (which the later versions of webpack support) or using AMD-style requires.This solution eliminates all overhead network and compilation latency, unnecessary data fetching and is most maintainable.

*Note: it has nothing to do, as the other answer asserts, with preventing "blocking javascript execution". You could just as well embed the templates directly in the HTML in `template` or `<script type="text/template">` tags and defer parsing/ compilation of their contents, but that would increase the load time of the initial request.*

Comment: I have not used webpack, so correct me if I'm wrong. From what I understand, by loading on-demand you mean that it will be loaded every time the user tries to do something while webpack would only load it once when it is first required. Is that it or is there some other concept here?

Comment: I am specifically asking for the elimination of all overhead network and compilation latency. I understand that the templates would be precompiled, but I do not understand the network part. Or is it because there would be no connections needed to be established unlike the static imports and fetch requests?

Comment: Edit (since I cannot edit a comment so late after posting it): I'm pretty sure that you meant multiple precompiled templates can now be imported using AMD/webpack as otherwise using fetch requests/multiple separate dynamic imports I would be making multiple connections. I hope I am correct in my understanding.

Comment: @asharpharp You are mostly correct in your understanding. Webpack does not transform Handlebars tpls, you need to impl. that (eg webpack plugin). [Dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) are an ES6 feature that is polyfilled by webpack. For every dynamic import, webpack creates a separate bundle.js. Under the hood, dyn. imports make requests and return a promise, so *they do not reduce the amount of requests required*. That's ok, what matters is not how many requests, but *how they are spread over time* using available bandwidth.