# How does webpack reduce overhead network latency?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

Yesterday I posted this question: [Difference between importing Handlebar templates and fetching them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986109/difference-between-importing-handlebar-templates-and-fetching-them/62986618#62986618). The question was opinion-based and was rightfully closed, but the topic that I became interested in from it is not opinion-based. Tyblitz was very helpful, but I am not sure if I understood correctly. I first thought he meant caching, then I thought he meant that bundles would be requested at once. From his final comment, I think the advantage of using webpack in regards to latency is that multiple requests would be made concurrently.

```
const foo = await import...;
const bar = await import...;
```

I understand this would first wait for foo to be imported and then wait for bar while webpack would make both requests concurrently. Is that it or am I not understanding something? I do not see how else it would be better for the latency to spread requests over time.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack builds one large JavaScript file with all your JavaScript code, and then changes your html files to include just that instead of slowly requesting one JS file at a time, possibly waiting until one downloads until getting the next (twice the latency) -- that's exactly what the code you pasted would otherwise be doing, `await` is the opposite of concurrency.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to make sure I had finally understood correctly.